# Apache error page 404 - Apache Tomcat/9.0.20 / cve-2018-11784

Tags: security, tomcat, http-headers, content-security-policy

I am trying to validate an issue within our company site
As the apache is outdated & am trying to validate mentioned CVE

i Am inserting // in the url with path healthcheck
and message redircting to /healthcheck/
is it validated

[error page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMNNE.png)

I tried with health check and the message header returning with one /

references
https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/testing-for-cve-2018-11784-apache-struts-2-open-redirect-vulnerability

Comment: I'd not bother validating. Just update